# Why is gradient descent with momentum considered an exponentially weighted average?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent

I recently watched [Andrew Ng's video on SGDM](https://www.coursera.org/learn/deep-neural-network/lecture/y0m1f/gradient-descent-with-momentum). I understand that the momentum term updates the gradient by weighting the last gradient and using a small component of V_dw. I don't understand why momentum is also known as exponentially weighted average. Also, in Ng's video at 6:37 he says using Beta = 0.9 effectively means using an average of the last 10 gradients. 
Can someone explain how that works? To me, it's just a scalar weighting of 1-0.9 to all the gradients in the vector dW.

Appreciate any insight! I feel like I'm missing something fundamental.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pick a gradient component, call it $g_a$. Let $g_{a,i}$ denote measured gradient on iteration i.

Then we set $g_{a,1} = \beta g_{a,1} + (1-\beta)g_{a,1} = g_{a,1}$

$g_{a,2} = \beta g_{a,1} + (1-\beta)g_{a,2}$

$g_{a,3} = \beta g_{a,2} + (1-\beta)g_{a,3} = \beta^2 g_{a,1} + \beta (1-\beta)g_{a,2} + (1-\beta)g_{a,3}$

$g_{a,4} = \beta g_{a,3} + (1-\beta)g_{a,4} = \beta^3 g_{a,1} + \beta^2(1-\beta)g_{a,2} + \beta(1-\beta)g_{a,3} + (1-\beta)g_{a,4}$

You can see how old gradient terms live on, but are geometrically (exponentially) weighted via powers of $\beta$, with the power increasing by 1 for every iteration old that gradient term is. $\beta^i $ decreases as $i$ increases, given that $\beta < 1$.  So old terms die out to insignificance after enough iterations, depending on the value of $\beta$.

Comment: That was a brilliant explanation! I'm just wondering, in Ng's video he said using beta = 0.9 would effectively average over the last 10 gradients. However ,0.9^10 = 0.34. The weighting by beta started to get insignificant somewhere around 20 iterations where 0.9^20 = 0.12. What are your thoughts on this Mark?

Comment: I don't know. I've watched a few Andrew Ng videos on topics I already knew quite well, and he seems to say some strange things, or at least the viewer could easily be misled. I'd rather read a good book or paper.

Comment: @nababs It's because "effectively average" implies a rough similarity to a *uniformly* weighted ("simple") moving average over the past 10 iterations. It's the idea of a "characteristic time" or "e-folding time" (0.9^10 ~ 1/e), which is the common measure of where an exponential "cuts off". Over 20 iterations, the weight decreases so much that it's not close to uniform. If you compute it over some made-up data with smooth trends/cycles, you will find that the beta = 0.9 exponential average is closer to the 10-iteration simple average than to the 20-iteration simple average.

Comment: @nanoman You should write this up as an additional answer.

Comment: My comment only answers a small part of the question (repeated by OP in a comment) and piggybacks on your nice answer to the main question. I don't have anything to add about gradient descent, only on how to think about exponential averages. Feel free to incorporate into your answer.